# while web scraping how to check if data not exist then pass other line

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping

hi i am trying to get data with web scraping but in page  sometimes my requested tags are  not available therefor i need to pass those data if it is not available or how can i get those data with their tags

```
          import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from datetime import datetime
    
    header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'}
    
    base_url = "https://www.avva.com.tr/outlet"
    main_url = "https://www.avva.com.tr"
    r = requests.get(base_url, headers=header)
    
    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        books = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "ItemOrj col-3"})
        my_date = datetime.now()
        result = []
        for book in books:
            title = book.find('a')['title']
            link = main_url+book.find('a')['href']
    
            picture = book.find('img')['src']
            print(picture)
    
    
    else:
        print(r.status_code)
```

```html
<img class="resimOrginal" src="/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/bisiklet-yaka-baskili-t-shirt-aaba.jpg"
 data-original="/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/bisiklet-yaka-baskili-t-shirt-aaba.jpg"
 alt="Bisiklet Yaka Gofre Baskılı T-Shirt"
 data-second="/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/bisiklet-yaka-baskili-t-shirt-3be5.jpg">


<a class="detailLink" title="Bisiklet Yaka Baskılı T-Shirt" href="/bisiklet-yaka-baskili-t-shirt-16570">
<video class="autoPlay urunVideo_d155fc1010134240876e75d9b2b1c6e1" data-blokmoduleid="" width="400" height="400"
       poster="/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/bisiklet-yaka-baskili-t-shirt-5c09.jpg" muted=""
       onloadeddata="this.play();" loop="" autoplay="" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="">
    <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/440368865.hd.mp4?s=31f6e9c527b8439f1a02f20443b6e224fbc760e6&amp;profile_id=174"
            type="video/mp4">
</video>
</a>


<a class="detailLink detailUrl" data-id="14523" title="Ultrasoft V Yaka Düz T-Shirt" href="/v-yaka-t-shirt-14523">
<img class="resimOrginal" src="/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/v-yaka-t-shirt-29dd.jpg"
     data-original="/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/v-yaka-t-shirt-29dd.jpg" alt="Ultrasoft V Yaka Düz T-Shirt"
     data-second="/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/v-yaka-t-shirt-390c.jpg">
</a>
```

and this is my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Red\Desktop\json\ftp.py", line 20, in <module>
picture = book.find('img')['src']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/o-yaka-t-shirt-ca53.jpg
/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/bisiklet-yaka-baskili-t-shirt-56fa.jpg
/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/bisiklet-yaka-nakisli-t-shirt-f4f2.jpg
/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/bisiklet-yaka-nakisli-t-shirt-2b21.jpg
/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/v-yaka-t-shirt-29dd.jpg
```

Comment: Use this line `if not book.find('img'):continue` just before `picture = book.find('img')['src']`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to first select the `img` object and test if it is different from `None`. If yes, then select the `src`.

```py
picture = book.find('img')
if picture!=None:
   picture_src = book.find('img')['src']
   print(picture)
```